# innerHTML not changing on setInterval

Tags: javascript, html, date, setinterval, innerhtml

In this javascript, "seconds left" should decrease every second but this do not happen.
`innerhtml` do not change the value for `<span id='timer'>` while `innerHTML` for `<span id='id'>` is working.

```
<script>
var lastdate=1373814606250;
var today=1373388292527;
var d,h,m,s;
function displayDate()
{
    today--;
    d=(lastdate-today)/86400000;
    h=(d-Math.floor(d))*24;
    m=(h-Math.floor(h))*60;
    s=(m-Math.floor(m))*60;
    document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML=Math.floor(d)+" Days "+Math.floor(h)+" hours "+Math.floor(m)+" minutes "+Math.floor(s)+" seconds";
    document.getElementById('id').innerHTML=today;
}
</script>
<body onload="setInterval('displayDate()',1000)">
<span id='timer'></span><br/>
<span id='id'></span>
</body>
```

See it [Working here](http://ezone.host-ed.me/stack.html)

**EDIT**
Here today and lastdate is date in milliseconds.

Comment: alert() the timer value, see what it says.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The innerHTML of the first span works too
but the content never changes.
`Math.floor(d)+" Days "+Math.floor(h)+" hours "+Math.floor(m)+" minutes "+Math.floor(s)+" seconds"` gives every time the same result.

Answer (score 2):

I understood There was logical error in calculating seconds.
It should be

```
today=today+1000;
```

Because of milliseconds not seconds

Comment: @Pete , It is a count down timer, Therefore today's time will increase ,last date is constant. so (lastdate-today) will decrease every second if today=today+1000 executes every second.

Comment: yes I know but in the code you had today--; that's why I asked. Anyways the good thing is you worked it out.